# Debugging C .dll files from a C# application

Tags: c#, c, debugging, gcc

I have C# application that makes use of some C libaries(which I have written and built using gcc). I'm trying to investigate a bug and would like to step into the C code when debugging my C# application in VS2008. How do I build my C librarys with the debug information I need for visual studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you should do is to enable unmanaged code debugging. Right-click on your project -> Properties -> Debug -> Check the "Enable unmanaged code debugging" (note that the image below is from VS2010, but VS2008 should look similar):

[image: VS 2010]

Step 2 is to build your DLL with the proper debugging information (PDB).

Microsoft has some tutorials on debugging in mixed mode:

- [Walkthrough: Debugging a Solution that Includes Both Managed and Native Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228818%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)
- [How to: Debug Native DLLs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c91k1xcf.aspx)
- [How to: Debug in Mixed Mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kbaht4dh%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

There are several questions on SO related to the topic:
[How to attach debugger to step into native (C++) code from a managed (C#) wrapper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57840/how-to-attach-debugger-to-step-into-native-c-code-from-a-managed-c-wrappe) and [Debugging Visual Studio 2010 DLL Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3662035/debugging-visual-studio-2010-dll-project)

Comment: Thanks I have already tried this but nothing happens when I try and step into a call to the C .dlls I think I need something like a .pdb file but am not sure how to create one from gcc.

Comment: @Lirick How do I build the .dll with debug info using gcc?

Comment: @Dunc I don't think you can generate PDBs with GCC... a while ago I read something about it, but I can't find it now. I'll get back to you if I can find any of the articles I read.

Comment: @Lirick I don't have to be tied to GCC. I'll try and build using an MS compiler.

Comment: @Dunc If you use the VS compiler, then you should be good to go.